# Passing Custom objects from WCF service to Client

Tags: c#, wcf, object, wsdl

Just need some help with this.

I have written a WCF service which passes through a list of custom objects (these objects are marked as serializable, so they pass through fine).

What do I need to write in the client to be able to receive these objects? I'd like to be able to receive them without having a definition of the class locally. I tried getting them as an object but I get the error

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<TestService.Member>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<object>'

Hope this is enough information, any pointers would be useful.

Comment: What does your WCF interface look like?  You should be able to simply update the service reference.  It will create the proxy classes for you.

Comment: simply 

   [OperationContract]
   List<Member> GetAllMembers();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to do a couple of things:

1) Create a custom class for this collection class that inherits from System.Collections.Generic.List

2) Decorate this new class with CollectionDataContract

3) In the client, edit reference.svcmap and add an entry for this new item to the CollectionMappings section. To find the svcmap, show all files in the project and expand the WCF service reference.

For the class:

```
[CollectionDataContract]
public class MemberCollection: List<Member>
```

For the svcmap:

```
  <CollectionMapping TypeName="MyNameSpace.MemberCollection" Category="List" />
```

Comment: So if I do this, what will the client see?

Comment: You should be able to link the member class and collection source code to the client project and then the client project will be able to use the complete functionality of these classes without having to re-add business logic or non-serialized members to the WCF-generated classes.